# duplicate key name while upgrading hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

while trying to upgrade hive from 2.1.0 to 2.3.0 getting below error
(actually upgrading emr 5.7.0 to 5.8.0)

`init hive-metastore schema]/returns: 0: jdbc:mysql://connection_string-> CREATE INDEX PCS_STATS_IDX ON PART_COL_STATS (DB_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,PARTITION_NAME) USING BTREE`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns: Error: Duplicate key name 'PCS_STATS_IDX' (state=42000,code=1061)`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns:`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns: Closing: 0: jdbc:mysql://connection_string:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns:  at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:586)`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns:  ... 8 more`
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Hadoop_hive::Init_metastore_schema/Exec[init hive-metastore schema]/returns: *** schemaTool failed ***`

Is there a way to resolve without manually dropping already created index PCS_STATS_IDX in hive external metastore?

Answer (score 0):

This is also something I've observed with external hive metastore databases on RDS instances for EMR clusters. It does not appear as if AWS has a good workaround yet for any of the emr-5+ versions - it's almost as if it should be able to skip these init hive-metastore scripts if the metastore schema has already been created. One possible approach at working around this is to let EMR start up its own hive local metastore (so start the EMR cluster without making changes to the initial hive-site.xml), and after the cluster has started, run an EMR step that stops hive-server2 `sudo stop hive-server2`, modifies the `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` to point the Hive Metastore at the external RDS instance by inserting these properties :

```
      <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>username</value>
      </property>

      <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>password</value>
      </property>

      <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://<rds instance connection string>:3306/db_name?createIfNotExist=true</value>
      </property>
```

And restart hive-server2 (`sudo start hive-server2`).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your Hive Distribution Version and Metastore schema Versions are different.
Use @[Kyle Meyer] way to spin up your emr and execute below command to check the versions:
schematool -dbType dbType -info
If they do not match use schematool to upgrade from 2.1.0 to 2.3.0:
schematool -dbType mysql -initSchemaTo 2.3.0

This will give you errors which you are facing now. To solve this, connect to your database using any client like SQL Workbench. It will mostly give you errors like "table_name/Indexes already exists."
Delete those tables/indexes using sql client. But you will have to delete those tables/indexes all together. So you will have to delete the table, then execute the command. If it again gives error for some other table/index, you will have to delete previous tables along with the current table in the error. It will take time but you will be able to upgrade the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> drop database IF EXISTS metastore;
```

hive-site.xml

```
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
```

deleting the metastore DB cleared my issue